# How can I show that on $[-1,0]$ $|\sin(x)|\le|x|$?

Tags: functions, inequality

It's pretty obvious to me as I see the plot of the two functions but how can I prove it with some algebra?

Comment: That does not seem true. Did you mean: $|\sin(x)|\leq|x|$?

Comment: yeah, I'm sorry, thanks for the correction

Comment: What tools do you have available?  Do you know, for example that $\sin x\le x$ for $x\ge 0$?

Comment: The Lagrange Form of the Taylor Remainder Theorem?    Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder

Comment: The inequality comes from any arc between two point is longer than the straight line between the same points. Draw the triangle and the circle out and you will see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the mean value theorem:

There is some number $c$ between $x$ and $0$ for which
$$
\sin' c = \frac{\sin x - \sin 0}{x - 0}.
$$
Since $|\sin'c|=|\cos c|\le 1$, we have
$$
\left|\frac{\sin x} x \right| \le 1,
$$
so
$$
|\sin x| \le |x|.
$$
There is no need to assume $x$ is in $[-1,0]$ to get this conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

By mean-value theorem, if $-1 \leq x < 0$, then
$$
|\sin x - \sin 0| = |\sin x| \leq |x|\sup_{0 < t < x}|\cos t| \leq |x|.
$$

Answer (score 2):

So here's an answer involving Calculus:

consider $f(x)=x-\sin x $

$f'(x) =1- \cos x > 0$

for $x \in [0,1]$, $f$ is increasing, so $f(x)>f(0)=0$ for $x \in [0,1]$

which means $x>\sin x \implies |x|>|\sin x|$ since $x$ and $\sin x$ is positive here.

for $x \in [-1,0]$, $f$ is increasing, so $f(x)<f(0)=0$ for $x \in [-1,0]$

which means $x<\sin x \implies |x|>|\sin x|$ since $x$ and $\sin x$ is negative here.

Therefore $|x|>|\sin x|$ for $x \in [-1,1]$

Answer (score 2):

(image taken from robjohn's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/75151/7327))

A geometrical proof can be seen in the following image:

$\sin x$ is the height from $C$ which is smaller than $BC$, which, in turn is smaller than the length of the arc $BC$, which is equal to $x$.

[image]